# How to call a function in polymer 2.0 on button onclick or anchor tag click?

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am seeing functionality like `Compute function` where i can use a function to compute same thing and then retrun something to that textcontent area but how to use them on button onclick or anchor onclick .

for example :

```
<dom-module id="x-custom">

  <template>
    My name is <span>[[_formatName(first, last)]]</span>
  </template>

  <script>
    class XCustom extends Polymer.Element {
      static get is() {return 'x-custom'}
      static get properties() {
        return {
          first: String,
          last: String
        }
      }
      _formatName(first, last) {
        return `${last}, ${first}`;
      }

    }

    customElements.define(XCustom.is, XCustom);
  </script>

</dom-module>
```

In this case the `_formatName` is manipulated in   and we get resultant in html.

But how to to in button onclick and

1. So that i can manipulate for send some `http` request .
2. Also manipulate some data inside the function .

**Polymer 2.0**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer . First of all for two way binding you also check the `polymer 1.0` doc for data binding that is in brief .

And then you can read `polymer 2.0` doc but i don't see more for data binding event there.

I will say read both.
https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates

This have example for custom event .
https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/events.html#custom-events

```
<dom-module id="x-custom">
  <template>
    <button on-click="handleClick">Kick Me</button>
  </template>
  <script>
    class XCustom extends Polymer.Element {

      static get is() {return 'x-custom'}

      handleClick() {
        console.log('Ow!');
      }
    }
    customElements.define(XCustom.is, XCustom);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Also if you want argument to pass to the function you can do this.

```
<dom-module id="x-custom">
      <template>
        <button on-click="handleClick" data-args="arg1,arg2">Kick Me</button>
      </template>
      <script>
        class XCustom extends Polymer.Element {

          static get is() {return 'x-custom'}

          handleClick(e) {
            console.log('Ow!');
            console.log(e.target.getAttribute('data-args'));
           // now you got args you can use them as you want
          }
        }
        customElements.define(XCustom.is, XCustom);
      </script>
    </dom-module>
```